# History tag scope

Tags: discussion, tags

The [history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag is a hodgepodge of all sorts of things but I think it might be better off just deleted if it isn't going to collect [apple-history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-history) (history of the company, computers, etc.—only found a few of these). Browser history is already covered in [browser](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser). Logs and bash history are covered in tags related to their apps.

Comment: I've seen multiple uses, such as [call history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375143/iphone-list-of-calls-of-a-contact), [software revision history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375558/what-was-the-first-version-of-macos-to-ship-with-the-vim-text-editor), and [bash history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/369862/ignore-duplicates-when-browsing-bash-history). The [tag:history] tag has no guidance/wiki, and [generic Apple history questions seem to be off-topic](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3216/154794).